# Magento form validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form-validation

When using jquery `.change` on an input the event will only be fired when the input loses focus

In my case, I need to make a call to the service (check if value is valid or empty) as soon as the input value is changed. How could I accomplish this? this validation for without using submit event.

Answer (score 2):

Open file `js/prototype/validation.js`

Find the following section

```
Validation.defaultOptions = {
    onSubmit : true,
    stopOnFirst : false,
    immediate : false,
    focusOnError : true,
    useTitles : false,
    addClassNameToContainer: false,
    containerClassName: '.input-box',
    onFormValidate : function(result, form) {},
    onElementValidate : function(result, elm) {}
};
```

and change `immediate : false,` to `immediate : true,`

Or you can create new js file with content

`Validation.defaultOptions.immediate = true;`

and add it below `js/prototype/validation.js`

Or add inline js before your form creation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Validation.defaultOptions.immediate = true;
<script>
```